# Is there a efficient ubuntu build besides the stock Ubuntu build?

Tags: compiling, google

Is there any more efficient ubuntu, the one with the best performance compared to the stock ubuntu.

Is there any documentation addressing these kind of builds?

I have heard of goobuntu build being used by google engineers but none of its details are opened to public.

Thus unity perform better than gnome in terms of performance?

Any kind of documentation addressing any of these issues would be really of great help.

Comment: Are you looking for a more lightweight desktop environment? In that case you can try Lubuntu (using LXDE) or Xubuntu (using XFCE) for example.

Comment: "efficient"? So Ubuntu is inefficient?  How so? "Thus unity perform better than gnome in terms of performance?" That largely depends on hardware and the users ability to overcome hardware related issues (the (not open source) nVidia driver performs better than AMD's version). Same for your NIC: some perform lousy on linux. Then again: either of these 2 has different features. Drop any kind of module, software and efficiency goes up. Goes for gnome, unity, lxde, etc.  The core for all is the same...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

short answer is no the developers are great at optimizing Ubuntu.

The longer answer is perhaps, depends on your hardware and willingness to compile a kernel.

Your hardware drivers are in the kernel and you may get better performance from identifying your hardware and determine if there are better drivers.

See https://www.linux.com/learn/recompile-your-kernel-perfect-fit, gentoo documentation, and [Does compiling a linux kernel make the OS faster?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/99759/does-compiling-a-linux-kernel-make-the-os-faster)

See also https://fun.irq.dk/funroll-loops.org/

You may also benefit from a different window manager such as lubuntu .

Other then that, without more information , who knows ?